# Why restrict my ability to change my vote once I have editing priveleges?

Tags: discussion, editing, voting

Yesterday I intended to upvote an answer, but accidentally downvoted. I did not notice this and did not change it within the five-minute window for changing votes. Later that day I noticed a drop on 1 in rep and discovered the accident.

I could not change my vote. But since I have editing priveleges, I edited the answer trivially (inserting 3 spaces in its source text) and then I was able to change my vote.

I don't really understand the reason to lock in votes after a certain amount of time in the first place, but I have read that it is to prevent some kind of gaming of the system. If the idea is really to prevent gaming of the system, then I guess I should not be allowed to game the system with my trivial edit either.

Or maybe editing rights should come with the right to change one's votes?

Comment: If someone were gaming the system, they would probably want to do so anonymously, and edits are not anonymous.

Comment: I've had to do this kind of thing, once, because of a misplaced click on a mobile phone!  It seems like a reasonable workaround for what is such an infrequent occurrence.

Comment: @hardmath that works only if you have editing priveleges, which require about 4x as much reputation as I have.  Recently I made a pocket-dialed downvote and had to run to the community for help.

Comment: @OscarLanzi: Okay, but this 3+ year old Question was about changing votes when you do have editing privileges.  If you don't, then your best chance is to discover voting errors within the five-minute window mentioned above.